# FFMPEG command to crop and transpose video comes out zoomed in bad quality

Tags: android, video, ffmpeg, crop

I'm trying to convert an mp4 video with dimensions usually 960x720 into a sqaure 480:480 video but it comes out looking squished usually, the command is

```
"-y -i %s -vf crop=480:480,transpose=%d -threads 5 -metadata:s:v rotate=0 -c:v libx264 -crf 27 -preset ultrafast -c:a copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc %s";
```

Am I missing something, do I need to down scale first or something?

**EDIT adding full console output. The ffmpeg command is updated, but the goal still remains the same, take an arbitrary video and square crop it

```
07-14 22:30:32.813: D/ffmpeg(30354): -y -i /data/data/com.myapp.app/cache:temp/i7h4ajm0nim1mbcnrqotvrhhsc.mp4 -vf scale=iw*sar:ih,transpose=1 -threads 5 -metadata:s:v rotate=0 -c:v libx264 -crf 27 -preset ultrafast -c:a copy -bsf:a aac_adtstoasc -aspect 1:1 /data/data/com.myapp.app/cache:temp/p1t3bhs0oa3lpqa67g5i9ninm9.ts
07-14 22:30:32.903: D/ffmpeg(30354): new time reamining 9283
07-14 22:30:32.913: D/FFmpeg(30354): Running publishing updates method
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354): WARNING: linker: /data/data/com.myapp.app/files/ffmpeg has text relocations. This is wasting memory and prevents security hardening. Please fix.
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354): ffmpeg version n2.4.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354):   built on Jun  3 2015 21:56:01 with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354):   configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/Users/Brian1/development/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi- --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/Users/Brian1/development/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot --enable-pic --enable-small --enable-libx264 --enable-pthreads --disable-muxers --enable-muxer=mpegts --enable-muxer=mp4 --disable-demuxers --enable-demuxer=mpegts --enable-demuxer=mov --enable-demuxer=mpeg --enable-demuxer=mp4 --disable-debug --disable-decoders --enable-decoder=h264 --enable-decoder=aac --disable-devices --disable-encoders --enable-encoder=libx264 --disable-network --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/Users/Brian1/development/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/Users/Brian1/development/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a-neon --extra-cflags='-I/Users/Brian1/development/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all -mfpu=neon' --extra-ldflags='-L/Users/Brian1/development/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs=-lm --extra-cxxflags=
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354):   libavutil      54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354):   libavcodec     56.  1.100 / 56.  1.100
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354):   libavformat    56.  4.101 / 56.  4.101
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354):   libavdevice    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354):   libavfilter     5.  1.100 /  5.  1.100
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354):   libswscale      3.  0.100 /  3.  0.100
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354):   libswresample   1.  1.100 /  1.  1.100
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354):   libpostproc    53.  0.100 / 53.  0.100
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354): Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/data/data/com.myapp.app/cache:temp/i7h4ajm0nim1mbcnrqotvrhhsc.mp4':
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354):   Metadata:
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354):     major_brand     : mp42
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354):     minor_version   : 0
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354):     compatible_brands: isommp42
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354):     creation_time   : 2015-07-15 05:30:32
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354):   Duration: 00:00:02.75, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 9315 kb/s
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354):     Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 960x720, 10062 kb/s, 29.97 fps, 29.97 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354):     Metadata:
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354):       rotate          : 90
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354):       creation_time   : 2015-07-15 05:30:32
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354):       handler_name    : VideoHandle
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354):     Side data:
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354):       displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354):     Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 151 kb/s (default)
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354):     Metadata:
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354):       creation_time   : 2015-07-15 05:30:32
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354):       handler_name    : SoundHandle
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354): [libx264 @ 0xb6808800] using SAR=4/3
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354): [libx264 @ 0xb6808800] using cpu capabilities: none!
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354): [libx264 @ 0xb6808800] profile Constrained Baseline, level 3.1
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354): [adts @ 0xb685b000] Using AVStream.codec.time_base as a timebase hint to the muxer is deprecated. Set AVStream.time_base instead.
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354): Output #0, mpegts, to '/data/data/com.myapp.app/cache:temp/p1t3bhs0oa3lpqa67g5i9ninm9.ts':
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354):   Metadata:
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354):     major_brand     : mp42
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354):     minor_version   : 0
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354):     compatible_brands: isommp42
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354):     encoder         : Lavf56.4.101
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354):     Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (libx264), yuv420p, 720x960 [SAR 4:3 DAR 1:1], q=-1--1, 29.97 fps, 90k tbn, 29.97 tbc (default)
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354):     Metadata:
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354):       handler_name    : VideoHandle
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354):       creation_time   : 2015-07-15 05:30:32
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354):       rotate          : 0
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354):       encoder         : Lavc56.1.100 libx264
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354):     Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, 151 kb/s (default)
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354):     Metadata:
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354):       creation_time   : 2015-07-15 05:30:32
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354):       handler_name    : SoundHandle
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354): Stream mapping:
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354):   Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (h264 (native) -> h264 (libx264))
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354):   Stream #0:1 -> #0:1 (copy)
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354): Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354): frame=   17 fps=0.0 q=27.0 size=       0kB time=00:00:00.36 bitrate=   0.0kbits/s    
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354): frame=   33 fps= 32 q=27.0 size=     164kB time=00:00:01.15 bitrate=1163.1kbits/s    
07-14 22:30:35.963: D/ffmpeg(30354): frame=   46 fps= 30 q=29.0 size=     213kB time=00:00:01.33 b
```

Comment: You would better specify the `aspect` param to `1` as you have 480x480 video output.

Comment: ok well how do I do that?

Comment: Try inserting `-aspect 480/480` before you specify the output file.

Comment: The below link provides multiple option to support crop operation on the video. http://video.stackexchange.com/questions/4563/how-can-i-crop-a-video-with-ffmpeg

Comment: There are some decent examples there but no info for square cropping and down sizing

Comment: crf 27 is pretty bad quality isn't it?

Comment: scale NOT crop. keep aspect ratio instead of converting to true square...    -filter:v scale="960:trunc(ow/a/2)*2"

Comment: @RobertRowntree can you elaborate on what the variables stand for? ow i presume is output width

Comment: @rogerdpack crf 23 is default I think 27 isn't great but this is running on mobile devices where speed is priority

Comment: OW expression preserves aspect ratio of the frames while scaling it to 960 Height.  scale is diff from crop . should have used value= 480 not 960  . since u need scale it down.

Comment: oh those aren't variable placeholders, they are literal strings that ffmpeg understands?

Comment: full ffmpeg command line and console output please?

Comment: @rogerdpack added console output

Comment: @RobertRowntree it seems almost counter intuitive that scaling will square crop but actually cropping it will distort the aspect ratio. Think of an image 500:1000px if I crop 500 pixels from the center it would just remove 250 px from the top and bottom but the image would not lose aspect ratio, thats what i'm trying to do

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can try this (takes care of cropping AND downsizing)...

`ffmpeg -i input.file -s 480x480 -vf crop=480:480,setdar=1:1,setsar=1:1 output.mp4`

`-s` will set scale (video canvas area) 
`crop=480:480` will crop from centre.. if you need from specific use: `crop=480:480:pos-X:pos-Y`
`setdar` will set Display Aspect Ratio 
`setsar` will set Sample Aspect Ratio

**Results:** (screen grabbed MP4 stills via **[MPC-Home Cinema](https://mpc-hc.org/downloads/)**)

[image]

Comment: some devices I tested on actually still seem slightly distorted, shouldn't Sample Aspect Ratio be the initial apsect ratio?

Comment: Sorry I dont have a testing Android  device on hand (only computer screen). Does `dar=72:72` or even `dar=172:72` work better? Check **[this article](https://spreadys.wordpress.com/2014/03/17/resizing-in-ffmpeg/)** for handy advice, and **[this article](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/175090/burning-a-video-file-with-non-standard-aspect-ratio-to-dvd/175507#175507)** is useful too. You could do Pixel Aspect calculations using both `sar` and `dar` based on input video's width & height.  `DAR / SAR = PAR`.