# Combine 2 .FLV videos

Tags: c#, video, ffmpeg, flv

For the last 4 hours I've been trying to combine 2 .flv files into one using ffmpeg (or well, just C# in general).

Here's what I got so far:
I've converted both the videos to .mp4 videos:

```
"-i " + videoFileLocation + " -c copy -copyts " + newConvertedFileLocation
```

I have then combined the two .mp4 files into a single one using:
(txtPath is the text file with the two mp4 file locations)

```
"-f concat -i " + txtPath + " -c copy " + saveLocation
```

This ends up with an mp4 file which contains the combination of both the videos BUT with the following fault:

The length of the first video is **0:05**

The length of the second video is **6:11**

However the length of the combined video is for some reason **07:51** - thus the video runs at a slower pace than it should.

Furthermore the audio is async with the video.

What am I doing wrong here?

I haven't used ffmpeg before and I just wanna get this working.

**Any help is greatly appreciated!**

As requested here is the output from running 'ffmpeg -i input1.flv -i input2.flv':

```
ffmpeg version 2.7 Copyright (c) 2000-2015 the FFmpeg developers   built with gcc 4.9.2 (GCC)...

Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from 'filepath\input1.flv':   Metadata:
    major_brand     : isom
    minor_version   : 512
    compatible_brands: isomiso2avc1mp41
    creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
    encoder         : Lavf53.24.2   Duration: 00:00:05.31, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 1589 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: h264 (Main) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p, 1280x720 [SAR 1:1 DAR 16:9], 1205 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 12800 tbn, 50 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      handler_name    : VideoHandler
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 384 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 1970-01-01 00:00:00
      handler_name    : SoundHandler Input #1, flv, from 'filepath\input2.flv':   Metadata:
    audiosize       : 4476626
    canSeekToEnd    : true
    datasize        : 23876671
    videosize       : 19004263
    hasAudio        : true
    hasCuePoints    : false
    hasKeyframes    : true
    hasMetadata     : true
    hasVideo        : true
    lasttimestamp   : 372
    metadatacreator : flvtool++ (Facebook, Motion project, dweatherford)
    totalframes     : 9298
    encoder         : Lavf56.36.100   Duration: 00:06:11.92, start: 0.080000, bitrate: 513 kb/s
    Stream #1:0: Video: h264 (High), yuv420p, 646x364 [SAR 1:1 DAR 323:182], 400 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #1:1: Audio: aac (LC), 44100 Hz, stereo, fltp, 96 kb/s At least one output file must be specified
```

Comment: There should be no need for your first command to remux from FLV to MP4. You should show the complete console output of: `ffmpeg -i input1.flv -i input2.flv`.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I Have added the output from the concat command.
I'm sorry that the text is so clumpsy but it wasn't formatted in any way from the console.

Comment: I'm not looking for the output from the concat command, but the output from the command I provided in my first comment.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard
What about output? I'm getting an error stating I need to specify output? Do you just want me to add -c -copy outputfilepath?

Comment: No, just provide what is outputted. I want to see info about your ffmpeg build and the FLV inputs. Using ffmpeg with just inputs is a way to see file info.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard
Ahh I see. I have updated my question with the output.

Comment: The video streams have a different width and height, and the audio streams vary in sample rate and channel layout. You should make them the same with scale and other filters and concat them with the concat filter.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard
Ahh I see.
I don't suppose you could show me an example in regards to how to accomplish this?

Comment: Well for a start one video is 1280w x 720h and the other video is 646w x 364h so you need to decide what final output size you want. For rescaling tips you can check **[my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31435727/2057709)** but you also need to handle the audio. I would suggest take one file at a time and re-encode to your one set of preferences for picture size, audio format and data rates. All these things can be Googled. Last advice is dont mix H.264 profile (High & Main) for more universal playback stick to "Baseline" profile (ie: if you remux to MP4 for mobile).

Comment: @VC.One
Thanks for your answer.
I've done my best to convert the intro to match the main videos specs however the result is still not right.
I feel like my issue right now is different from my original issue so I started a new question where I have described my efforts in details:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34097770/issue-when-combining-2-video-files-after-matching-the-specs

You are more than welcome to take a look!